# View post form return null?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having problems to return a model using a form.

The problem is when I submit the form, the values are null even though I've specified that returns a model

This is my controller

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P5uY.png]

And this is my View that returns null.

```
@model MyEnglishDictionary.Models.Dictionary
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="p-4 border rounded">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="Word"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input asp-for="Word" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Word" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="Meaning"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input asp-for="Meaning" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Meaning" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="Pronunciation"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input asp-for="Pronunciation" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Pronunciation" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success">Back To List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts{
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is my Dictionary controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyEnglishDictionary.Data;
using MyEnglishDictionary.Models;

namespace MyEnglishDictionary.Controllers
{
    public class DictionaryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public DictionaryController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_db.Dictionaries.ToList());
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Models.Dictionary word)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(word);
            }

            _db.Add(word);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Dictionary model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyEnglishDictionary.Models
{
    public class Dictionary
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Word { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Meaning { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Pronunciation { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am using Net Core 2.1, but I have some few projects that I use the same way to pass the form model from View to controller and they work.

Comment: probably you didn't add binding attribute to your model `[BindProperty]`, can you post your controller in the question not as picture.

Comment: Where is your   @Html.AntiForgeryToken() method?

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov with Asp.Net Core 2 or later the form tag will automatically inject antiforgery token into html form elements, see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-antiforgery-configuration)

Comment: You should post your controller code in the answer instead of screenshots, its much harder for people trying to help you

Comment: Could you add you `Dictionary` class?

Comment: There is my Model and the full Controller

Comment: @LazZiya I've set the bind property of `[Key]` to Id and `[Required]` to word and meaning and still does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the name of the parameter and fields.

For your issue, it is caused by that you defined a field which is `Word` and the parameter is `word` which caused the binding failed.

Try to change the `public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Models.Dictionary word)` to `public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Models.Dictionary dictionary)`.

Answer (score 1):

change the `word` parameter name to something else like `_word`, it seems like the compiler doesn't accept it as a parameter name in c#.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Models.Dictionary _word)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(_word);
    }

    _db.Add(_word);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

btw, I didn't see it in the reserved keywords [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the properties to your model. In your case:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Word, Meaning, Pronounciation")] Dictionary word)
```

Further reading:
[Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: with .Net Core you don't have to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` because it will be injected automatically into the form tag see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-antiforgery-configuration) for more details

Comment: @LazZiya Thanks, did not know that.